# Python HTTP POST/GET trigger for Google Assistant (IFTTT)

Tags: python, http, post, webhooks, ifttt

I recently discovered, that you can add custom commands to Google Assistant with IFTTT. You can set it to make a GET/POST request (webhooks) containing specific words from your command. I'm trying to create an IoT style device (using a Pocket C.H.I.P.) to control various electronic devices.

What's the simplest way of listening to HTTP POST requests with python?

Comment: what's the connector in IFTTT that I can set the HTTP GET/POST?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, for anyone interested I used Tornado:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

import CHIP_IO.GPIO as GPIO
import CHIP_IO.Utilities as UT

import time

UT.unexport_all()

GPIO.setup("XIO-P2", GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup("XIO-P3", GPIO.OUT)

class Handler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        state = self.get_argument("state")
        print state
        if state == "off":
            GPIO.output("XIO-P2", GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output("XIO-P2", GPIO.LOW)
        elif state == "on":
            GPIO.output("XIO-P3", GPIO.HIGH)
            time.sleep(1)
            GPIO.output("XIO-P3", GPIO.LOW)

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", Handler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8080)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```